# I need data security camera for human detecting, where can I find it?

Tags: machine-learning, image-recognition

I'm in a human detecting project, but data is some videos captured by many cameras that both capture a person with different angle, and I can't find it.

- Do you know where I can find data and Can you send me the link?

Comment: This is not a link finding service. Google exists for that exact purpose. This site is for programming questions. Please spend some time taking the [tour] and reading through the [help] pages before posting your next question here.

Answer (score -1):

try the **opencv** documentation and tutorials to find your data. It also has libraries that aid in human body detection.

Comment: also, this is **not** the site to ask these questions. Use a search engine.